# Update multiple values in table with array value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a field (level) in table 1 (inspjc) with data from table 2 (reqs) with a different name for the "level" field (reqs_level).

Both tables have the same identity field name (reqs_id) with corresponding data.

The "reqs" table have all the "reqs_id" numbers in it (about 1000 entries), where as only some of the "reqs_id" numbers appear in the "inspjc" table. 
The levels depicted in the "reqs_level" field ranges from 0 to 108, thus there is no way to know the sequence or use of these assigned levels, they appear random as per each reqs' requirement.

I have tried a few of the examples in stack overflow, but none came close.

Below is my latest attempt:

```
<?php
include("../xxx");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
$query = "SELECT `inspjc`.`reqs_id`,`reqs`.`reqs_level`
            FROM `inspjc` 
            JOIN `reqs`
            ON `inspjc`.`reqs_id`,`reqs`.`reqs_id`
            WHERE `inspjc`.`inspjc_id` = '$inspjc_id' 
            AND `reqs`.`reqs_id` = `reqs`.`reqs_no`";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    extract($row);
    $ids = array("$reqs_id");
    $level = array("$reqs_level");
    }

include("../xxx");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
$query = "UPDATE `inspjc` SET `level`='".$level."' WHERE `reqs_id` IN ('".implode(',', $ids)."') AND `inspjc_id` = '$inspjc_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query4. "
        .mysqli_error($cxn));           
?>
```

Some Data Examples of the tables 
(please note "reqs" has 55 columns and 1093 entries and "inspjc" has 9 columns and 78 entries)

```
reqs
reqs_id     status_id   reqs_required   reqs_level
00324       3           Erection        32
00526       7           Erection        5
00112       8           Modify          96

inspjc
reqs_id     inspjc_id   inspjc_date     level
00112       K3456Y      2015-06-30      ***96***
00526       K3456Y      2015-04-22      ***5***
```

Comment: Normally, one table is joined to another on the condition that a value in a column in the first table is equal to a value in a column on the second table.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry the "reqs_id" values find in the "inspjc" table will always appear in the "reqs" table, but not all "reqs_id" will be found in the "inspjc" table. Its a one to many relationship...

Comment: So you should reflect that fact in your SELECT query (although you don't really need a SELECT query here, but we'll come to that in due course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I got it right, following is the query that sorted the issue:

```
UPDATE `inspjc` i
    JOIN `reqs` s
    ON i.`reqs_id` = s.`reqs_id`
    SET i.`level` = s.`reqs_level` 
    WHERE i.`inspjc_id` = '$inspjc_id'
```